# form.submit() with JQuery returns character encoding error message

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to submit a form with jQuery but it doesn't work. I get this strange error message in Firebug (in German, sorry) and assume there is some strange character in the html?

> Die Zeichenkodierung des Reintext-Dokuments wurde nicht deklariert.
>   Das Dokument wird in manchen Browser-Konfigurationen mit verstümmeltem
>   Text dargestellt, wenn das Dokument Zeichen außerhalb des
>   US-ASCII-Bereichs enthält. Die Zeichenkodierung der Seite muss im
>   Transferprotokoll deklariert werden oder die Datei muss eine
>   Byte-Order-Markierung als Kodierungssignatur verwenden.

---

Google translate says:

The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document is in some browser configurations shown with garbled text when the document contains characters outside the US-ASCII range. The encoding of the page must be declared in the transfer protocol, or use the file must be a Byte Order Mark as encoding signature

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en

Comment: ["Das Internet is nicht fur gefingerclicken und giffengrabben. Ist easy droppenpacket der Routers und overloaden der Backbone mit der spammen und der me-tooen. Ist nicht fur gewerken bei die Dummkopfen. Die mausklicken Sichtseeren keepen das Bandwidth-spewen Hands in die Pockets muss, relaxen und watchen das cursorblinken."](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article09-100)

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have a character encoding problem. Try re-saving the offending HTML document in an editor that lets you specify character encoding. Save the HTML file in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) to be safe.

You can also specify UTF-8 encoding with a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or in HTML5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and after few hours of investigating I have noticed that the reason was same path for HTTP Handler and for template.

So basically you cannot register HTTP handler in httpHandlers section in your config:

```
<add verb="POST" path="myHandler.aspx" type="MyProject.HttpHandlers.MyHttpHandler"/>
```

when you use some template named myHandler.aspx.
That error was thrown after I have submitted form even that I haven't called in that place my handler.